# How to reduce load times of an excel workbook data source in Power Query Excel?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have an Excel workbook with over 50 Tables. This workbook will act as the source to a Quote Engine, which again is designed in Excel. I am using Power Query to import and transform data from the Source Workbook into the Quote Tool.

Currently all 50 queries refer to one Source Workbook. I am curious about whether Power Query "Opens" and "Closes" the workbook for each query. Can I benefit from some performance improvement by loading the workbook into memory somehow? I would like to know how you have optimized such load times.

Comment: Try to compare the loading times when the data is in Excel files and when the data is in plain flat CSV files. If flat files are loaded much faster, then there might be some room for optimizations.

Comment: Sure that's a good suggestion. Will try it!